# Windows 7 - Additional RAM installed, but usable amount did not increase?

Tags: windows-7, memory

We have just upgraded a PC running Windows 7 Enterprise Edition (32bit) to have 4gb of memory instead of 2gb.

Previously, there was 989mb of usable memory (with 2gb total installed). After upgrading, the computer now shows 4gb of total memory with 989mb usable.

Why has the available memory not increased? How can I make this memory available for usage?

As stated, it is recognizing the memory but not showing it as usable memory.

Thanks.

**Update**

Looking at Resource Monitor, it appears that the Hardware Reserved Memory is 3gb. So when I inserted the additional 2gb of memory, it was all taken as Hardware Reserved Memory and added not a single MB to Usable Memory.

What could cause this?

My other machines are only reserving roughly 1gb.

**Update - Solution Found**

It looks like the graphics card was faulty and consuming all RAM except for 989mb regardless of how much RAM was installed. It has been replaced with a different graphics card and Usable Memory is now what was expected (Roughly 3gb).

Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: You should check in the BIOS menu if the memory is picked up. Also, are you sure the new ram is 100% compatible with your motherboard and CPU?

Comment: Check this Article :
The usable memory may be less than the installed memory Link :
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978610

Comment: I anticipate the usable memory being less than the installed memory. However, I have installed 2 additional GB of memory and did not receive a single additional MB of usable memory. That seems very abnormal. I have another machine here running the same operating system, with 4gb installed, and it has slightly over 3gb in usable memory.

Comment: So you didn't have the full 2GB usable previous to the upgrade. Why didn't you troubleshoot this issue before spending the money and time on upgrading the RAM?

Comment: @Rudolph - Sorry for the delay. The BIOS menu does show the additional menu. I am not 100% sure. It shows up on the BIOS menu, and shows up as installed memory, but does not provide any additional usable memory compared to the old RAM.

Comment: @joewerty - Because there was only 2gb total before. It did not strike me as abnormal that only about half of such a small amount would be available. Windows consuming around a GB of memory seems standard on the 4 machines I have available to me.

Comment: The 3gb of hardware-reserved memory is a problem. I recal something about "mscconfig" boot option , ensure that "maximum memory" is unchecked. Also, this might indicate that you have a bad memory slot. Try booting with a single dimm in a single slot, and move the dimm between boot(s) to see if you can identify a slot that doesn't work. Try this with each stick of ram.

Answer (score 0):

Well the upgrade has been successful, I’d say there could be a process using a that memory, have you looked via Task Manager or [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find it?

Comment: The task manager shows a total available memory of 989mb, with a remaining amount of 87mb. That's with nothing running. However, if you go to Computer > Properties, it shows Installed Memory of 4gb, with a total of 989mb usable. The same amount as when there was only 2gb installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell us what the make/model number of the laptop/all-in-one is ... if that is what you are using.

If you are using a desktop machine then tell us either the make/model number or if it's a custom build then the make/model number of the motherboard.

There are LOTS of older machines out there that (because of BIOS limitations) will only recognize 2 GB of RAM max. I even ran into one where the manufacturer (and Crucial) said "2 GB max." When you put in 4 GB it didn't work, but, amazingly, 3 GB would work and be recognized by the OS. The manufacturer had really hobbled things in the BIOS.

Comment: The computer is a desktop. A Dell Vostro 220 & BIOS version 1.2.4. To my knowledge it is not customized.

Comment: OK ... It's a Dell Vostro 220. That should be able to take 2x2GB of RAM. The characteristics of the (most compatible) RAM appear to be: DDR2-800 aka PC2-6400, a CL(CAS Latency) of 6, unbuffered (non-registered/server) RAM, non-ECC RAM. All of that in an organization of 256Meg x 64. Are those the specs of the RAM your trying to upgrade to? If you don't know then let us know what the manufacturer and part number of the DIMMs are.

Comment: Sounds like that's what I have. Here's what my slip says: 2 - 2GB DDR2-800 (PC2-6400) Non-ECC Unbuffered, 240 Pin, 1.8V CL=6 Memory 128X8